# Why I got error SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=4.18.60 in execuing below query

Tags: db2, ibm-data-studio

When I run:

```
select * from sys.server_role_members ;
```

got below error:

```
SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=4.18.60
```

Comment: Not sure, but have a look at this. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n204.html

Answer (score 1):

As you seem to be a beginner, you need to know that when asking for help with Db2, it is important to always write your Db2-version  and the Db2-server operating system (Z/OS, i-Series(formerly AS/400), or Linux/Unix/Windows ). That's because the three platforms have different capabilities and sometimes the SQL is different also, and the catalog is different.

You get that error because your query is meant for Microsoft SQL-Server databases only.

Your query cannot work on Db2 because Db2 does not allow user-created schema names to begin with SYS.  Some IBM-created schema-names can start with SYS for example SYSIBM and SYSCAT but these are reserved for the catalog and they get created by Db2 during database creation.

Db2 has tables like SYSIBM.SYSROLEAUTH and SYSIBM.SYSROLES  and (on Linux/Unix/Windows) a set of views on these in the SYSCAT schema.

For example, if your Db2-server runs on Linux/Unix/Windows, then these views exist [SYSCAT.ROLES](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0050612.html)  and [SYSCAT.ROLEAUTH](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0050619.html) .

In addition, Db2 for Linux/Unix/Windows provides table function [AUTH_LIST_AUTHORITIES_FOR_AUTHID](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0052898.html)   which is quite useful.

If your Db2-server runs on i-Series, then *different* tables/views exist. That's the reason you need to know *which platform* of Db2 you are using, and write that in your questions.

Comment: I also got the same error for below queries.select * from SYSIBM.SYSROLEAUTH; 
select * from SYSIBM.SYSROLES; 
select * from SYSPROC.AUTH_LIST_AUTHORITIES_FOR_AUTHID;